# What does "e is 65537 (0x10001)" mean?

Tags: openssl, primes

I want to know what the output `e is 65537 (0x10001)` means. It happens during the RSA Key Generation using `openssl genrsa`. I know that the dots mean that the number has passed a probe division and the plus is printed out after it passed a miller rabin test. But i can't figure out what the last info message before the RSA key is printed out means.

I can't find it in the openssl docs. And I could use it in term paper on prime number generation. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The "e" is the public exponent, in `openssl genrsa`, you can use the option `-F4` or `-3` to choose between 65537 and 3.

For information on public exponent, you may take a look on this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c